# Content Import Drupal

Tags: import, drupal-8

I tried and can import content without reference..

but the problem is i always fail to import with node, tax, user referenced...

[The error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLE3Z.png)

the csv example i download from the menu have two title is that normal ?

perhaps there is anyone can help

how exactly to do that ? i can't find anywhere the manual..
the readme file not clearly explain it..

I'm using content import module

Thankyou..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

https://www.drupal.org/project/csv_importer

It is better than content importer module

Comment: sorry i could find in the docs how tu use it properly.. to create proper csv..

so basically like this..

title,field1,field2,referendField1,referencedField2,

is that right ? and should we change to the ID referenced not the string ? can i use stirng instead ?

sorry im new to drupal and i want to migrate my data to my new drupal website..

thanks

Comment: edited.. i can import the node with referenced

should we change to the ID referenced not the string ? can i use stirng instead ?

sorry im new to drupal and i want to migrate my data to my new drupal website..

thanks

Comment: It is simple csv importer you have to put field name in the top row. For the referenced entities simply put the related ids. All will be imported.

Comment: thankyou sir.. but can i use string instead of id for fererenced entities ?

Comment: For this module you can't only id referenced is allowed

Comment: To achieve string instead of id for fererenced entities use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds